# ng-mouseover event passing 'this' (self) reference to DOM not working. is there anyother way rather than using core javascript event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling, dom-events

I want to get 'self DOM' on mouse over event, so I am passing 'this' on `ng-mouseover` event but its not working.
please refer below code.

```
<a href="#" ng-mouseover="console.log(this)" >Mouse over me!</a>
```

I want it work with angular js only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$event`:

```
<a href="#" ng-mouseover="mouseMe($event)" >Mouse over me!</a>
```

JS

```
$scope.mouseMe = function (event) {
    console.log(event);
};
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - $event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-).

Answer (score 2):

With *AngularJS* you can get the **$event** simply requiring it into the template by typing:

`<a href="#" ng-mouseover="onMouseover($event)" >Mouse over me!</a>`

Then in your controller you can get the DOM element, target of this event with:

```
$scope.onMouseover = function ($event) {
    //
    console.log($event.target);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help . I was trying 'this' as argument , but $event worked for me.